# Xerces-C validate xml with hardcoded xsd

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xerces, xerces-c

I'm writing a library which takes xml files and parses them. To prevent users from feeding inalid xmls into my application i'm using xerces to validate the xml files via an xsd.

However, i only manages to validate against xsd-files. Theoretically an user could just open this file and mess around with it. That's why i would like my xsd to be hardcoded in my library.

Unfortunately i haven't found a way to do this with XercesC++, yet.

That's how it is working right now...

```
bool XmlParser::validateXml(std::string a_XsdFilename)
{
    xercesc::XercesDOMParser  domParser;
    if (domParser.loadGrammar(a_XsdFilename.c_str(), xercesc::Grammar::SchemaGrammarType) == NULL)
    {
        throw Exceptions::Parser::XmlSchemaNotReadableException();
    }

    XercesParserErrorHandler parserErrorHandler;

    domParser.setErrorHandler(&parserErrorHandler);
    domParser.setValidationScheme(xercesc::XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
    domParser.setDoNamespaces(true);
    domParser.setDoSchema(true);
    domParser.setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);

    domParser.parse(m_Filename.c_str());

    return (domParser.getErrorCount() == 0);

}
```

`std::string m_Filename` is a member variable holding the path of the xml i validate.

`std::string a_XsdFilename` is the path to the xsd i validate against.

`XercesParserErrorHandler` inherits from `xercesc::ErrorHandler` and does error handling.

**How can i replace `std::string a_XsdFilename` with something like `std::string a_XsdText`?**
Where `std::string a_XsdText` contains the schema definition itself instead of a path to a file containing the schema definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll describe three ways of how to hardcode your XSD in your program:

- by loading the XSD from a file path (this is what your example program does right now)
- by loading the XSD from a string (this is what you ask for)
- by loading the XSD from a precompiled binary

## Loading the XSD from a file path

Boris Kolpackov suggests in a [blog post](http://codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/03/15/validating-external-schemas-xerces-cxx/) that applications should provide the  XSD schema files by themselves rather than looking up the schema files through the **xsi:schemaLocation** or **xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation** attributes found in the XML file.

In the blog post there is a link to [*load-grammar-dom*](https://codesynthesis.com/~boris/data/load-grammar/load-grammar-dom.cxx) , an example program (put in the public domain) that makes use of the  [xercesc::DOMLSParser::loadGrammar](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMLSParser.html#af57fb3e5bb73ea44acad1528e93a13c9) function:

```
user@linux:~$ load-grammar-dom
usage: load-grammar-dom [test.xsd ... ] [test.xml ...]
user@linux:~$
```

## Loading the XSD from a string

If you would like to pass the XSD file contents as a string, you would need to use another overload of 
[xercesc::DOMLSParser::loadGrammar](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMLSParser.html#aa1899d16956c733c9f6e6f3ca07fa0ab)
where you pass

`const DOMLSInput *source`

instead of

`const char *const systemId`

The DOMLSInput could be created with the help of [xercesc::MemBufInputSource](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classMemBufInputSource.html) and [xercesc::Wrapper4InputSource](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classWrapper4InputSource.html) like this

```cpp
xercesc::Wrapper4InputSource source(
    new xercesc::MemBufInputSource(
       (const XMLByte *) (a_XsdText.c_str()),
    a_XsdText.size(),
    "A name");
```

(Adapted somewhat from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15829424/757777 but untested)

## Loading the XSD from a precompiled binary

Included in the software [CodeSynthesis XSD](https://codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/) the [**embedded**](https://git.codesynthesis.com/cgit/xsd/xsd/tree/examples/cxx/tree/embedded) example (that is put in the public domain) demonstrates how to use

[xercesc::BinInputStream](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classBinInputStream.html) and 
[xercesc::XMLGrammarPool::deserializeGrammars](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXMLGrammarPool.html#a49c9d8b945202dc52efac9a49777b76c)

to load a precompiled XSD schema.

See also [README](https://git.codesynthesis.com/cgit/xsd/xsd/tree/examples/cxx/tree/embedded/README).

The example contains the program `xsdbin` that compiles XSD schema files into a binary file.

```
user@linux:~$ xsdbin --help
Usage: xsdbin [options] <files>
Options:
  --help                 Print usage information and exit.
  --verbose              Print progress information.
  --output-dir <dir>     Write generated files to <dir>.
  --hxx-suffix <sfx>     Header file suffix instead of '-schema.hxx'.
  --cxx-suffix <sfx>     Source file suffix instead of '-schema.cxx'.
  --array-name <name>    Binary data array name.
  --disable-multi-import Disable multiple import support.
user@linux:~$
```

In the [makefile](https://git.codesynthesis.com/cgit/xsd/xsd/tree/examples/cxx/tree/embedded/makefile) the XSD schema file is precompiled by xsdbin and the result ends up inside the example executable.