# xml modification using codesynthesis-xsd

Tags: xml, codesynthesis

I wanted to know if [codesynthesis-xsd](https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) can be used to modify values of an xml. From the website I could see only about xml parsing. But in my program I want to do both parsing as well as editing the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to

- first parse the XML into the generated data object model
- then make a modification
- and finally serialize it back to XML

See for instance the [**library**](https://git.codesynthesis.com/cgit/xsd/xsd/tree/examples/cxx/tree/library) example in the **CodeSynthesis XSD** source package:

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll check the link. One more thing I wanted was schema validation of the xml. Is this also possible?

Comment: Yes, validating with a schema is possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275608/xerces-c-validate-xml-with-hardcoded-xsd/52464355#52464355

Comment: Thanks. One last related doubt. Codesynthesis-xsd is built on top of xerces, right? Actually I found about xerces first and then found xsd and I know there's some relation. But the documentation and the examples are a bit too much heavy for me in the beginning.

Comment: I imagine xsd to be a library which makes working with xerces a bit easier. I think after paying some more attention to the examples and the documentation I'll get a better idea.

Comment: Yes, __CodeSynthesis XSD__ makes use of __Xerces-C__  and yes working with  __CodeSynthesis XSD__ together with __Xerces-C__  is easier and more convenient than working with only __Xerces-C__ .